# Change RAM clock in BIOS of Intel NUC10

Tags: memory, bios, clock, intel-nuc

I am using Intel NUC (NUC10i7FNH)
Because of some reasons I want to reduce my RAM clock speed. I did some search and find this document from intel that said you can do this by clicking Advanced Button (not advanced tap) and then go to performance tab and change settings.

https://www.intel.com/content/dam/support/us/en/documents/mini-pcs/nuc-kits/NUC8i7HxK-Overclocking-Assistant.pdf

But there is no "advanced button" in my BIOS! I can just see configs in read-only mode! Based on another intel document, newer devices have a different BIOS version called Aptio and I think the previous document just using older BIOS version called "Visual BIOS Core"

https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000006028/intel-nuc.html

My question is, how can I change RAM clock on this device with Aptio bios?

UPDATE:
I take photos from bios.
Advanced menu tab:
[image]

Performance menu tab:
[image]

Thanks,

Comment: There should be a Memory menu on the performance tab that lets you select a memory profile. That should allow you to do some. If that isn't there you probably won't be able to modify the RAM speed.

Comment: @Seth I just add two photos of my bios interface

Comment: As per the AptioV BIOS Glossary: `Displays the current memory speed. Defined as Current Host Clock Frequency x Memory Reference Multiplier x Memory Multiplier.` though as per Page 26 there should be an option for Memory Profiles. Check that it's not hidden by the arrow on the left. If it's not there you probably won't be able to change those settings and thus the RAM speed. What's the reason anyway that you want to do that?

Comment: @Seth well, the system is very unstable and gets crashes frequently (blue screen crash) I know the problem is not related to OS and the whole system is original hardware except for the RAM. the RAM test said it is ok, so I want to reduce RAM speed to make sure about the source of the problem.